# How do i filter a grouped kendo datasource on items collection

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I have a grouped datasource.  The datasource appears to only let me filter by the "value" / grouped item.  How do I filter on properties such as name that are in the grouped items, "items" collection?

I populate datasource

```
categories.push({ parentNode : d.parentNode, 
    node: d.node, 
    identity: d.identity,  
    key: d.key, 
    value : d.value, 
    categories : []
    });
```

I set datasource and group

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({data: categories);                
dataSource.group({ field: "value" });
```

I then want to filter by node but the only option to filter appears to be the grouped value.

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of the dataSource initialization with us?

Answer (score 0):

I punted and changed the data source to hierarchical which allowed me to do what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just add square bracket in group line

`dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({data: categories);

dataSource.group([{ field: "value" }]);`

Try This one. !